# Randomly Offset Array Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

If I have

```
var numbs = [1, 2, 3, 4]

var new numbs = [1 + Math.random() * 2 - 1, 2 + '' , 3 + etc....
```

So I end up with something like:

```
var new numbs = [.877, 2.166, 2.456, 4.235]
```

There has to be a better way to do this...

Comment: Can you describe what you need the numbers for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Javascript

```
function randomBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var numbs = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    numbsOffset = numbs.map(function (value) {
        return +(value + randomBetween(-1, 1)).toFixed(2);
    });

console.log(numbsOffset);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jg6rr/)

Or you can use a `for` loop if you don't want to use ECMAScript 5

Comment: why the `.toFixed` seems that OP wants numbers in the array?

Comment: That's what the `+` does.

Comment: Weird way of rounding if you ask me... Why not: `Math.round(num*100)/100` instead of type casting

Comment: I don't see how using `toFixed` is a wierd way.

Comment: For once it's super slow compared, it's weird to make a number to a string and back to a number... ?? http://jsperf.com/tofixed-vs-math-round-2

Comment: This is perfect; Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks! I needed an existing array to have randomly offset values, similar but not the same to orignal. Simple noise per se... Only problem is there isn't too much variation in the randomness but I should be able work with it from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This gives you an array with 4 items all collected using Math.random()
var nums = Array.apply(null, Array(4)).map(function(v, key) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 100;
});
nums; // [0.64, 0.35, 0.36, 0.44]
```

You can then use `key` (the index) in your calculation:

```
// This gives you an array with 4 items all collected using Math.random()
var nums = Array.apply(null, Array(4)).map(function(v, key) {
    return key + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) / 100;
});
nums; // [0.36, 1.52, 2.35, 3.89]
```

---

```
var nums = Array.apply(null, Array(4)).map(function(){});
```

is basically the same as writing:

```
var nums = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
     nums.push( /*something*/ );
}
```

But you will get a closed scope.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() is basically used for generating random decimal numbers between 0 and 1. So if you are interested in obtaining integer elements,use Math.floor(Math.random()) or Math.ceil(Math.random()) or Math.round(Math.random()) as per your requirements.